# How to make a switch-case statement for CP5 buttons

Tags: processing

I constructed my buttons in a for loop like this:

```java
for(int k=1; k<25; ++k){
   cp5.addButton("LED" + str(k)) }
```

Now, I want to be able to use serial communication in a switch-case statement.
I tried this (

```java
void controlEvent(CallbackEvent event) {
  if (event.getAction() == ControlP5.ACTION_CLICK) {
    switch(event.getController().getAddress()) {
      case "LED1":
         println("Button 1 Pressed");
         if (port != null) port.write("1\n");
         break;
      case "LED2":
         println("Button 2 Pressed");
         if (port != null) port.write("2\n");
         break;
    }
  }
}
```

But it didn't work.

Comment: What does `event.getController().getAddress()` returns? It may be the wrong call, did you read the documentation? Maybe it's `.getName()` Reading [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65012168/how-to-clear-canvas-and-buttons-and-their-functuality-after-clicking-a-button/65015528#65015528) may also help you a little, it's about using a switch with buttons.

Comment: Ah yes that was the problem. It worked, thank you very much